# The type or namespace name 'XmlConfigurator' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, log4net, xmlconfigurator

The type or namespace name 'XmlConfigurator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing a namespace???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `log4net.dll` to your project and the `using log4net.Config;` namespace

Answer (score 1):

Your missing dll. Right click on your project and `Add Reference...` point to correct dll.

Comment: I'm not missing the DLL yet still get this

Comment: I used to use log4net and it wasn't this hard. I think they may have changed it and the net is now full of clashing advice. This time I gave up and used an SQL logging table.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility that you have not added the dll. This would require right clicking your project and adding the reference DLL. There is one other step that wasn't mentioned in the previous answers that I found relevant.

There is the possibility that you are not using the correct runtime. I found that log4net requires a full profile. For instance the client profile for .NET 4 will generate this error but if you use the full profile you will not experience this.